# Don't delete the existing css on an element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already some css style on my element (my element has 1500px of height). But when i tried to change the colors of it, the height was replaced by the colors putted, so the height of my element is deleted..

Here is the code :

```
document.getElementById("tabcmp0").style.backgroundColor = "#e9e9e9";
```

But i want to not replace the background color by the existing css style, i just want to add this background color to the css already existing, how to do this please ?

Comment: An element can have multiple background *images* but always only one background *color*. So whatever you try, it is not possible.

Comment: adding background color to an inline style would not effect the height of an element - please add code to the question that demonstrates this odd behaviour you claim

Comment: On the debogger of the browser, i can see that the height is replaced by the background color..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so this(`document.getElementById("tabcmp0").style.backgroundColor = "#e9e9e9";`) will replace your css with previous css, but you can do the following

there is multiple ways to solve your problem

> 1:Add class in javascript

in css

```
.class{
  background-color:#e9e9e9;
  height:1500px !important;
}
```

in JS

```
var element = document.getElementById("tabcmp0");
    element.classList.add("class");
```

> 2: If you are using jquery

```
$('#tabcmp0').css({'background-color':'#e9e9e9'});
```

and if you want to use multiple css

$('#tabcmp0').css({'background-color':'#e9e9e9', 'height':'1500px'});

hope this solves your problem

> As you edited your question, my answer will be changed and you can only have one css color at a time on a particular element,

what you can do now is add 2 `<div>` inside your element and add css on both the div separatly

like

```
<myElement>
   <div stlye="your backgroundcolor">
   </div>
   <div stlye="your backgroundcolor">
   </div>
</myElement>
```

Comment: The height is set by like this `var doc = document.getElementById("tabcmp" + i);
            doc.setAttribute("style", "height: " + 720 + "px");` , and not in the css file. I can tell you that the css putted before is replaced by the line `document.getElementById("tabcmp0").style.backgroundColor = "#e9e9e9";`...

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it should not overwrite your existing style.
You can check it in action [HERE](https://codepen.io/Patchy10/pen/RepepR)

Here is the code (maybe you can use it to find what you are missing or what is causing your issue).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#democlass {
    color: red;
    font-size:100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="democlass">Hello World</h1>
<p>Click the button to add an id background style to the h1 element.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("democlass").style.backgroundColor = "#e9e9e9"; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that the `font-size` doesn't change when adding the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: It don't overwrite your existing style if you already putted all of the css style on the css file, but if you create all of you css style with javascript, it will overwrite it.. :(

Comment: Then we need to see more of your code. Please attach your styling with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign(yourelement.style,{backgroundColor:"#e9e9e9",height:"1500px"});
```

Comment: Imagine that i already putted before on my code this : `var doc = document.getElementById("tabcmp" + i); doc.setAttribute("style", "height: " + 720 + "px");` . How can i tell him to add too the background color and don't replace it ?? @DennisFeldbusch

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi Then you should go on like this:
`doc.setAttribute("style", "backgroundColor : "#e9e9e9");`

Comment: It replace too my height putted before ... @DennisFeldbusch

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi Try something like `doc.setAttribute("style", "backgroundColor : "#e9e9e9; height: " + 720 + "px");`